# What does @[indexPath] do

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, literals

I followed a tutorial for using a `UITableView`. The finished code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        Message *message = [messageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.persistencyService deleteMessagesFor:message.peer];
        [messageList removeObject:message];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

My question is: What does `@[indexPath]` do? Is it the same as?:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is the same, its just the short notation for defining an array. You can do the same with NSDictionary and NSNumber as well. Here some samples [(and some more here)](http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray-and):

```
NSArray *shortNotationArray = @[@"string1", @"string2", @"string3"];

NSDictionary *shortNotationDict = @{@"key1":@"value1", @"key2":@"value2"};

NSNumber *shortNotationNumber = @69;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. It's a new feature of modern objective-C.

You can create new arrays with the literal `@`, like in the example you have. This works well not only for `NSArrays`, but for `NSNumbers` and `NSDictionaries` too, like in:

```
NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42;   // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"name" : NSUserName(),
    @"date" : [NSDate date],
    @"processInfo" : [NSProcessInfo processInfo] //dictionary with 3 keys and 3 objects
};

NSArray *array = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"]; //array with 3 objects
```

It nice for accessing the elements too, like this:

```
NSString *test = array[0]; //this gives you the string @"a"

NSDate *date = dictionary[@"date"]; //this access the object with the key @"date" in the dictionary
```

You can have more informations here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: I would like to set your answer as the accepted answer too, but unfortunately SO doesn't allow this. Cause Emilio was faster I must give him the credits for it. But nice explanation!